# Python's 'from ... import *' in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Is there anything equivarent to Python's 'from foobar import *' in Node.js?

Now I wrote the following code:

```
var foobar = require('foobar'),
    func1  = foobar.func1,
    gvar2  = foobar.gvar2,
    const3 = foobar.const3;
```

I think this is ugly, because a lot of names appeared twice.

Python provides smart solution which removes duplications:

```
from foobar import func1, gvar2, const3
```

Does Node.js provide similar way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not; at least, I am not aware of any way to do this easily.

Node uses the [CommonJS module system](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1), which requires a function, `require`, that returns an exported API for a module.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I hope that Node.js (or next generation JavaScript) supports more smart module/namespace system.

Answer (score 2):

```
function mixin(mod,scope)
{
    if (!scope) 
        scope=global;
    var module = require(mod);
    for (key in module)
        scope[key] = module[key];
}

mixin('http');
var s = createServer();
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a good idea to recommend this... importing all library functions to global scope seems wrong. Maybe it's not worth following the Python pattern sometimes.

Comment: `mixin('foobar', 'func1, gvar2, const3');` - let's assume there is a filter. I can see some use cases, but I never used such code myself

Comment: True. Module name, array of members to import, optional scope. Then it's similar to the pattern others use in `var someGlobal = require('module').onlyFunctionIWantToUse;`, but more.

Comment: Andrey, thank you for your advice. But adding values into 'global' is not what I want. I want to import values as local variables, like Python's behavior, in order not to change 'global'. But your advice seems cool. Thank you.

Comment: @kwatch When you declare variables at the top of a file, outside of any functions, they are added to the global scope, which makes them available anywhere in that file. Also, Andrey's method allows you to pass your own scope, although there is a typo in his example at the moment so it'll always apply to global. Something like this seems viable, although you'd have to include a module that provides this function or keep it in your project anyway.

Comment: The problem is, you can't declare variables whose names you don't know at the time you're writing the code. You can only add them to an object: either a local object, or the global scope (which is an object). So no, @kwatch, you can't import properties as local variables dynamically.